# How to store an R data frame in a java variable

Tags: java, r

I have a function in R which returns a data frame of different data types.

I am calling the R function from java.

But I am not getting how to call a R function which will return a data frame.

I use the below code to return an array of string.
What to do for a data frame.

```
String[] output_f1= c.eval("fun1(x)").asStrings();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package java_r_dataframe;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import org.rosuda.REngine.REXP;
 import org.rosuda.REngine.REXPGenericVector;
import org.rosuda.REngine.REXPMismatchException;
import org.rosuda.REngine.RList;
import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection;
 import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException;

 public class mymainclass {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws RserveException,   REXPMismatchException {

RConnection c = new RConnection();

c.eval("source(\"/home/Jayshree/Desktop/return_data2.R\")");
 RList a  = c.eval("return_dataframe_2()").asList();


 REXPGenericVector v = new REXPGenericVector(a);

 c.eval("source(\"/home/Jayshree/Desktop/return_data2.R\")");
 c.assign("x", v);
  String b = c.eval("return_dataframe_3(x)").asString();

  System.out.println(b);
  }}
```